# Material UI dialog popup with an icon on top?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a dialog with an icon at the top such as this:

[image]

This is currently what I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the container overflow css property to visible

```
.popupContainer {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Or make the icon's position absolute and give it a proper z-index

```
.popupContainer {
  position: relative;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 100;
}
```